# while loop, specify arguments in any order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
    const logs = [
        "channelCreate",
        "channelDelete",
        "channelPinsUpdate",
        "channelUpdate",
    ]

    let bee = logs.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < bee; i++) {
        while (args[1] == logs[i]) {
            if (args[1].startsWith("channelCreate")) {
                db.remove_logging(message.guildId, args[1])
                args.splice(1, 1);
            } else if (args[1].startsWith("channelDelete")) {
                db.remove_logging(message.guildId, args[1])
                args.splice(1, 1);
            } else if (args[1].startsWith("channelPinsUpdate")) {
                db.remove_logging(message.guildId, args[1])
                args.splice(1, 1);
            } else if (args[1].startsWith("channelUpdate")) {
                db.remove_logging(message.guildId, args[1])
                args.splice(1, 1);
            } else {
                return message.channel.send({ content: "log typ error" })
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to build a command, that looks something like this: `p!set log channelCreate channelDelete channelPinsUpdate channelUpdate`

I can type these arguments `channelCreate channelDelete channelPinsUpdate channelUpdate` but only in the correct order, so that everything is removed from the database. But I want that it doesn't matter how to specify the arguments, e.g. `channelPinsUpdate channelCreate channelUpdate channelDelete`

I suspect I am doing something wrong, but unfortunately I don't know what

Comment: What is in the `args` array?  Please show it or an example of it.

Comment: Also, the question discusses order of the command, but it is not clear what you're trying to do about the order.  Please explain more or show/describe multiple examples of different orders of commands and how you want to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

All you are doing is removing the log from db with same arguments so you can just do this instead:

```js
const logs = [
    "channelCreate",
    "channelDelete",
    "channelPinsUpdate",
    "channelUpdate",
];

if (!logs.includes(args[1])) return message.channel.send({ content: "log typ error" });

db.remove_logging(message.guildId, args[1]);
```

The code checks for valid log from logs array and if `args[1]` is invalid, it returns error. Otherwise, it executes `remove_logging` method of `db`.

Answer (score -1):

It's the logic of your loops that isn't consistent. You must first loop over the arguments and thus test if each of them is a log and thus execute your deletion. In this way, all the arguments will be compared to the logs and it doesn't matter the order of the arguments.
Try this:

```
for (let i = 1, arg; arg = args[i]; ++i) {
    if (arg.startsWith("channelCreate")) {
        db.remove_logging(message.guildId, arg)
    } else if (arg.startsWith("channelDelete")) {
        db.remove_logging(message.guildId, arg)
    } else if (arg.startsWith("channelPinsUpdate")) {
        db.remove_logging(message.guildId, arg)
    } else if (arg.startsWith("channelUpdate")) {
        db.remove_logging(message.guildId, arg)
    } else {
        return message.channel.send({ content: "log typ error" })
    }
}
```

Comment: That is really innefficient. It's better to fix the loop and create a spaguetti code with repetitive conditions :/

Comment: why to check all those when you can just do `logs.includes(args[1])` check and if it does, execute `db.remove_logging(message.guildId, args[1])` else send error message. You don't even have to use loops.

Comment: @Malik Lahlou How exactly do I do that? Of course it would be nice if I don't have so much code and can save some lines, but I would like to be able to specify several things